# Choose m points out of n that form the polytope with the maximum volume in hyperspace

Tags: optimization, computational-geometry

Let's say I have a set $A$ of $n$ points represented by real vectors of length $l$. What type of algorithm would I use to find the subset $B$ of $m$ ($m$ is arbitrary, to be chosen) points that maximizes the volume of the polytope with vertices defined by $B$?

Comment: After some research, it looks what I'm asking is how to find a "restricted" convex hull of the set. That is, the subset of size m of points that encloses most of the set as possible.